node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15 at Function.process_params (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
[0] npm run server exited with code SIGINT [1] npm run client exited with code SIGINT 
when i join router to my express and make a separate file it showing this kinda error that it couldn't found routes
this is Express file
import express from 'express';
import products from './data/products.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();
import connectDb from './config/db.js';
import productRoutes from './routes/productRoutes.js';

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

connectDb();//Mongo Connection
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running...');
});

app.use('/api/products', productRoutes)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));

This is my productRoute.js
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(products);
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === req.params.id);
    res.json(product);
});


export default router;

a solution where i could resolve this error

what does this mean "res.json(products);" in your productRoute.js file, if it is a file then you have forgot to import it or is it something else? add/define it

i have imported it from Dababase

in your productRoute.js, there isn't any import statement regarding products. kindly correct it
add this "import products from './data/products.js';" on top of your productRoute.js and make sure you can access ./data/products.js properly

Further, the routes i have imported in express file and there i mentioned "import products

products are imported wrong file. You need to do it in productRoute.js file
